# Dynamically fill text in textbox in powershell gui

Tags: powershell

I am creating a GUI for user creation. I have two text boxes, one for first name, second for surname. I'd like the GUI to display dynamically the whole name below these fields. Is that possible? I tried to put a lable there with a value `$Display_name_val.Text = $First_name_val.Text + " " + $Second_name_val.Text` but I got an error that op_Addition is not known for textbox. Same when I tried to use a label. Does this have a solution or does the display name have to be put in manually to be displayed?
Here's the complete code of the dialog box:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$AD_user_creation                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$AD_user_creation.ClientSize     = '480,600'
$AD_user_creation.text           = "AD user creation - WG Mustang"
$AD_user_creation.TopMost        = $false

$Display_name_lbl                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Display_name_lbl.text           = "User`'s real name"
$Display_name_lbl.AutoSize       = $true
$Display_name_lbl.width          = 25
$Display_name_lbl.height         = 10
$Display_name_lbl.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$Display_name_lbl.Font           = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$First_name_val                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$First_name_val.multiline        = $false
$First_name_val.width            = 120
$First_name_val.height           = 20
$First_name_val.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,10)
$First_name_val.Font             = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Second_name_val                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Second_name_val.multiline       = $false
$Second_name_val.width           = 120
$Second_name_val.height          = 20
$Second_name_val.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(330,10)
$Second_name_val.Font            = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$User_name_lbl                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$User_name_lbl.text              = "User logon name"
$User_name_lbl.AutoSize          = $true
$User_name_lbl.width             = 25
$User_name_lbl.height            = 10
$User_name_lbl.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70)
$User_name_lbl.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Display_name_val                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Display_name_val.Text           = $First_name_val.Text + " " + $Second_name_val.Text
$Display_name_val.width          = 250
$Display_name_val.height         = 20
$Display_name_val.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,40)
$Display_name_val.Font           = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$User_name_val                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$User_name_val.multiline         = $false
$User_name_val.width             = 250
$User_name_val.height            = 20
$User_name_val.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,70)
$User_name_val.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Password_lbl                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Password_lbl.text               = "Password"
$Password_lbl.AutoSize           = $true
$Password_lbl.width              = 25
$Password_lbl.height             = 10
$Password_lbl.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,100)
$Password_lbl.Font               = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Password_ini_val                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$Password_ini_val.multiline      = $false
$Password_ini_val.width          = 250
$Password_ini_val.height         = 20
$Password_ini_val.UseSystemPasswordChar
$Password_ini_val.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,100)
$Password_ini_val.Font           = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Password_conf_val               = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$Password_conf_val.multiline     = $false
$Password_conf_val.width         = 250
$Password_conf_val.height        = 20
$Password_conf_val.UseSystemPasswordChar
$Password_conf_val.location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,130)
$Password_conf_val.Font          = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Location_lbl                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Location_lbl.text               = "Location"
$Location_lbl.AutoSize           = $true
$Location_lbl.width              = 25
$Location_lbl.height             = 10
$Location_lbl.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,160)
$Location_lbl.Font               = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Location_val                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Location_val.multiline          = $false
$Location_val.text               = "Domain.com/ADM/Users"
$Location_val.width              = 250
$Location_val.height             = 20
$Location_val.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,159)
$Location_val.Font               = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Must_chg_pass                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Must_chg_pass.text              = "User must change password at next logon"
$Must_chg_pass.AutoSize          = $false
$Must_chg_pass.width             = 290
$Must_chg_pass.height            = 20
$Must_chg_pass.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,190)
$Must_chg_pass.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Cannot_chg_pass                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Cannot_chg_pass.text            = "User cannot change password"
$Cannot_chg_pass.AutoSize        = $false
$Cannot_chg_pass.width           = 250
$Cannot_chg_pass.height          = 20
$Cannot_chg_pass.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,220)
$Cannot_chg_pass.Font            = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$Cannot_chg_pass.Checked         = $true

$Pass_not_expires                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Pass_not_expires.text           = "Password never expires"
$Pass_not_expires.AutoSize       = $false
$Pass_not_expires.width          = 250
$Pass_not_expires.height         = 20
$Pass_not_expires.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,250)
$Pass_not_expires.Font           = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$Pass_not_expires.Checked        = $true

$Account_disabled_val            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Account_disabled_val.text       = "Account is disabled"
$Account_disabled_val.AutoSize   = $false
$Account_disabled_val.width      = 250
$Account_disabled_val.height     = 20
$Account_disabled_val.location   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,280)
$Account_disabled_val.Font       = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$GECOS_lbl                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$GECOS_lbl.text                  = "Description"
$GECOS_lbl.AutoSize              = $true
$GECOS_lbl.width                 = 25
$GECOS_lbl.height                = 10
$GECOS_lbl.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,310)
$GECOS_lbl.Font                  = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$GECOS_val                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$GECOS_val.multiline             = $false
$GECOS_val.width                 = 250
$GECOS_val.height                = 20
$GECOS_val.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,310)
$GECOS_val.Font                  = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$ADGroups_lbl                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$ADGroups_lbl.text               = "AD Groups"
$ADGroups_lbl.AutoSize           = $true
$ADGroups_lbl.width              = 25
$ADGroups_lbl.height             = 10
$ADGroups_lbl.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,340)
$ADGroups_lbl.Font               = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$TextBox1                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox1.multiline              = $true
$TextBox1.width                  = 250
$TextBox1.height                 = 160
$TextBox1.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,340)
$TextBox1.Font                   = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Confirm_Button                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Confirm_Button.BackColor        = "#00ff00"
$Confirm_Button.text             = "OK"
$Confirm_Button.width            = 100
$Confirm_Button.height           = 30
$Confirm_Button.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,550)
$Confirm_Button.Font             = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10,style=Bold'

$Cancel_button                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Cancel_button.BackColor         = "#ff0000"
$Cancel_button.text              = "Cancel"
$Cancel_button.width             = 100
$Cancel_button.height            = 30
$Cancel_button.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(350,550)
$Cancel_button.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10,style=Bold'

$AD_user_creation.AcceptButton   = $Confirm_Button
$AD_user_creation.CancelButton   = $Cancel_button

$AD_user_creation.controls.AddRange(@($Display_name_lbl,$First_name_val,$Second_name_val,$User_name_lbl,$Display_name_val,$User_name_val,$Password_lbl,$Password_ini_val,$Password_conf_val,$Location_lbl,$Location_val,$Must_chg_pass,$Cannot_chg_pass,$Pass_not_expires,$Account_disabled_val,$GECOS_lbl,$GECOS_val,$ADGroups_lbl,$TextBox1,$Confirm_Button,$Cancel_button))
```

Comment: Post your complete Code here for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the `$Display_name_val.Text` field *dynamically*. Utilise e.g. [Control.Validating Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating). Just add the following code snippet somewhere before `$AD_user_creation.controls.AddRange(…`:

```
$First_name_val.Add_Validating({
    $Display_name_val.Text = $First_name_val.Text + " " + $Second_name_val.Text
})
$Second_name_val.Add_Validating({
    $Display_name_val.Text = $First_name_val.Text + " " + $Second_name_val.Text
})
```

Answer (score 0):

See changes:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles() | Out-Null

$AD_user_creation                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$AD_user_creation.ClientSize     = '480,600'
$AD_user_creation.text           = "AD user creation - WG Mustang"
$AD_user_creation.TopMost        = $false

[void]$AD_user_creation.SuspendLayout()

$Display_name_lbl                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Display_name_lbl.text           = "User`'s real name"
$Display_name_lbl.AutoSize       = $true
$Display_name_lbl.width          = 25
$Display_name_lbl.height         = 10
$Display_name_lbl.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$Display_name_lbl.Font           = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$First_name_val                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$First_name_val.multiline        = $false
$First_name_val.width            = 120
$First_name_val.height           = 20
$First_name_val.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,10)
$First_name_val.Font             = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Second_name_val                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Second_name_val.multiline       = $false
$Second_name_val.width           = 120
$Second_name_val.height          = 20
$Second_name_val.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(330,10)
$Second_name_val.Font            = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$User_name_lbl                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$User_name_lbl.text              = "User logon name"
$User_name_lbl.AutoSize          = $true
$User_name_lbl.width             = 25
$User_name_lbl.height            = 10
$User_name_lbl.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70)
$User_name_lbl.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Display_name_val                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Display_name_val.Text           = ""
$Display_name_val.width          = 250
$Display_name_val.height         = 20
$Display_name_val.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,40)
$Display_name_val.Font           = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$User_name_val                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$User_name_val.multiline         = $false
$User_name_val.width             = 250
$User_name_val.height            = 20
$User_name_val.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,70)
$User_name_val.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Password_lbl                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Password_lbl.text               = "Password"
$Password_lbl.AutoSize           = $true
$Password_lbl.width              = 25
$Password_lbl.height             = 10
$Password_lbl.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,100)
$Password_lbl.Font               = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Password_ini_val                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$Password_ini_val.multiline      = $false
$Password_ini_val.width          = 250
$Password_ini_val.height         = 20
$Password_ini_val.UseSystemPasswordChar = $true
$Password_ini_val.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,100)
$Password_ini_val.Font           = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Password_conf_val               = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$Password_conf_val.multiline     = $false
$Password_conf_val.width         = 250
$Password_conf_val.height        = 20
$Password_conf_val.UseSystemPasswordChar = $true
$Password_conf_val.location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,130)
$Password_conf_val.Font          = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Location_lbl                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Location_lbl.text               = "Location"
$Location_lbl.AutoSize           = $true
$Location_lbl.width              = 25
$Location_lbl.height             = 10
$Location_lbl.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,160)
$Location_lbl.Font               = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Location_val                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Location_val.multiline          = $false
$Location_val.text               = "Domain.com/ADM/Users"
$Location_val.width              = 250
$Location_val.height             = 20
$Location_val.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,159)
$Location_val.Font               = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Must_chg_pass                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Must_chg_pass.text              = "User must change password at next logon"
$Must_chg_pass.AutoSize          = $false
$Must_chg_pass.width             = 290
$Must_chg_pass.height            = 20
$Must_chg_pass.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,190)
$Must_chg_pass.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Cannot_chg_pass                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Cannot_chg_pass.text            = "User cannot change password"
$Cannot_chg_pass.AutoSize        = $false
$Cannot_chg_pass.width           = 250
$Cannot_chg_pass.height          = 20
$Cannot_chg_pass.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,220)
$Cannot_chg_pass.Font            = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$Cannot_chg_pass.Checked         = $true

$Pass_not_expires                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Pass_not_expires.text           = "Password never expires"
$Pass_not_expires.AutoSize       = $false
$Pass_not_expires.width          = 250
$Pass_not_expires.height         = 20
$Pass_not_expires.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,250)
$Pass_not_expires.Font           = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$Pass_not_expires.Checked        = $true

$Account_disabled_val            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Account_disabled_val.text       = "Account is disabled"
$Account_disabled_val.AutoSize   = $false
$Account_disabled_val.width      = 250
$Account_disabled_val.height     = 20
$Account_disabled_val.location   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,280)
$Account_disabled_val.Font       = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$GECOS_lbl                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$GECOS_lbl.text                  = "Description"
$GECOS_lbl.AutoSize              = $true
$GECOS_lbl.width                 = 25
$GECOS_lbl.height                = 10
$GECOS_lbl.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,310)
$GECOS_lbl.Font                  = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$GECOS_val                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$GECOS_val.multiline             = $false
$GECOS_val.width                 = 250
$GECOS_val.height                = 20
$GECOS_val.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,310)
$GECOS_val.Font                  = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$ADGroups_lbl                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$ADGroups_lbl.text               = "AD Groups"
$ADGroups_lbl.AutoSize           = $true
$ADGroups_lbl.width              = 25
$ADGroups_lbl.height             = 10
$ADGroups_lbl.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,340)
$ADGroups_lbl.Font               = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$TextBox1                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox1.multiline              = $true
$TextBox1.width                  = 250
$TextBox1.height                 = 160
$TextBox1.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,340)
$TextBox1.Font                   = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Confirm_Button                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Confirm_Button.BackColor        = "#00ff00"
$Confirm_Button.text             = "OK"
$Confirm_Button.width            = 100
$Confirm_Button.height           = 30
$Confirm_Button.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,550)
$Confirm_Button.Font             = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10,style=Bold'

$Cancel_button                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Cancel_button.BackColor         = "#ff0000"
$Cancel_button.text              = "Cancel"
$Cancel_button.width             = 100
$Cancel_button.height            = 30
$Cancel_button.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(350,550)
$Cancel_button.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10,style=Bold'

$AD_user_creation.AcceptButton   = $Confirm_Button
$AD_user_creation.CancelButton   = $Cancel_button

$AD_user_creation.controls.AddRange(@($Display_name_lbl,$First_name_val,$Second_name_val,$User_name_lbl,$Display_name_val,$User_name_val,$Password_lbl,$Password_ini_val,$Password_conf_val,$Location_lbl,$Location_val,$Must_chg_pass,$Cannot_chg_pass,$Pass_not_expires,$Account_disabled_val,$GECOS_lbl,$GECOS_val,$ADGroups_lbl,$TextBox1,$Confirm_Button,$Cancel_button)) | Out-Null

$showFullName = { $Display_name_val.Text = ($First_name_val.Text + " " + $Second_name_val.Text) }

[void]$Second_name_val.Add_Leave( { & $showFullName } )
[void]$First_name_val.Add_Leave(  { & $showFullName } )

[void]$AD_user_creation.ResumeLayout()

$result = $AD_user_creation.ShowDialog()
[void]$AD_user_creation.Dispose()
```